# Any step function on $[a,b]$ is a simple function.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, simple-functions

My work:
To show this, I consider the function $\varphi:E\rightarrow R$ so that $\varphi(E)=\{c_{1},..c_{p}\}$ is a finite set and if $c_{1},..c_{p}$ distnict, then $\varphi = \sum_{j=1}^{p}c_{j}\chi_{E_{j}}$ where $E_{j} = \{\varphi = c_{j}\}$.

I don't how to start the next step. Could you please advice me as possible? Do I need to consider the open intervals?
Thanks.

Comment: What is your definition of step function?

Comment: I can called the step function $\psi:E\rightarrow R$ provided that there is a finite partition $a=t_{0}<t_{1}<...<t_{n}=b$ so that $\psi$ is constant on each of the open intervals $(t_{i-1}, t_{i})$.

Comment: now. Try to check the definition of simple. Does $\psi$ have a finite range?

Comment: Try to [look at here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/475862/step-function-and-simple-functions) and the answer to your question is obvious.

Comment: that is $E_{i}= (t_{i-1}, t_{i})$ since open intervals are measurable. We are done!!